Does azuredevops yaml support "extend" of entire pipeline including Triggers
My aim is to have a template file which also defines the triggers. I have lots of very similar pipelines and i would like to also predefine the branches on which they are triggered. My Problem is it still runs for all branches and not only the ones as defined in triggers of template. here a very simplified exmaple of the issue:
assume template.yml in git template_repo:
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
     - dev
     - main
 
steps:
  - script:|
        echo "I only run on dev and main but i do not :("

then in main yaml azure-pipelines.yml i want to extend from this like this:
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: template_repo
    type: git
    name: template/template_repo
 

extends:
    template: template.yml@template_repo

The problem is now that this pipeline from azure-pipelines.yml is also triggered on feature_xyz branch...not only on main and dev.
A workaround is to copy/past trigger from template.yml into all my azure-pipelines.yml files, but i would like to know if it just does not work with extend or if i am doing something wrong.
So i hope good old stack overflow can help since GPT seems to lie :D....

It doesn't look like you'll be able to define the trigger from the template. The pipeline definition appears to pick up the triggers from the source repository pipeline.yml only.
The documentation for extends isn't great. The only real example provided is through the 'security with templates', which is more skewed towards security than encapsulation and reuse.
The best way to understand what is happening is to download the YAML from the Edit Pipeline.

If you were to do this, you would see the final expanded YAML for your pipeline would look like this, and your trigger definition did not come through:
stages:
- stage: __default
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: 'Build job'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    steps:
    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: |
          echo "I only run on dev and main but i do not :("

The absence of the trigger is equivalent to not specifying a trigger, which means any change will trigger the pipeline.
There was one workaround that I thought might be possible: it is possible to define resources in an extends template and repository definitions can contain trigger definitions. Since the originating repository is labelled 'self' I thought you might be able to overload the self repository and define the triggers there. Unfortunately, only the ref parameter can be dynamic, and you get an error if you try and make the name property dynamic.
This doesn't work:
# template.yml
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: self
    type: git
    name: ${{ variables['Build.Repository.Name'] }} # error: unsupported
    ref: ${{ variables['Build.SourceBranch'] }} # valid
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - main
        - develop

steps:
- checkout: self


Thank you very much for the detailed explanation and trying the resources approach. So then i will just do good old copy paste in each pipeline for the triggers or use include template on the triggers. I think that's possible although i am not sure if i gain anything from having template for that :D which is more code than the actual triggers. Maybe for future renaming in one spot instead of 50... but anyways. Thank you.

I have found specifying the triggers in the pipeline.yml isn't terrible. Especially if you're creating a central reusable template to be consumed by others -- 1) it would be impractical for you to know the branch and paths that the pipeline consumers would want and 2) creating a prescriptive triggering mechanism would lead to an inflexible system.

As always it depends. I wanted to offer both. More modular reusable things like certain steps which can be used as include templates and for certain use cases an entire pipeline including the triggers. But it's fine. Now i have entire pipeline templates except for the triggers....
